# Getting MongoDB error on Write - quota exceeded

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-java, quota

I have a JAVA app which writes to a replicaset. Am using 3.0.7 version of MongoDB server.  The mongo-driver for Java is 3.0.4.
It was working just fine but now am getting the following error on ALL writes:

```
com.mongodb.MongoWriteException: quota exceeded
at    com.mongodb.MongoCollectionImpl.executeSingleWriteRequest(MongoCollectionImpl.java:487)
at com.mongodb.MongoCollectionImpl.update(MongoCollectionImpl.java:474)
at com.mongodb.MongoCollectionImpl.updateOne(MongoCollectionImpl.java:325)
```

Have looked at the MongoDB config documentation and I have not set any quota limits in mongod.conf. Am not using smallFiles either.

But I think am running into fileSize limits. The file sizes for my DB are as follows:

```
total 6240548
-rw------- 1 mongod mongod   67108864 Dec  8 16:55 2015.0
-rw------- 1 mongod mongod  134217728 Dec  8 12:15 2015.1
-rw------- 1 mongod mongod  268435456 Dec  8 12:15 2015.2
-rw------- 1 mongod mongod  536870912 Dec  8 12:15 2015.3
-rw------- 1 mongod mongod 1073741824 Dec  8 12:15 2015.4
-rw------- 1 mongod mongod 2146435072 Dec  8 16:06 2015.5
-rw------- 1 mongod mongod 2146435072 Dec  8 16:06 2015.6
-rw------- 1 mongod mongod   16777216 Dec  8 16:55 2015.ns
drwxr-xr-x 2 mongod mongod       4096 Dec  7 09:14 _tmp
```

The /etc/mongod.conf is as follows:

```
    storage:
       dbPath: /data/mongoDB
       indexBuildRetry: true
       repairPath: /data/mongoDB/repair
       journal:
          enabled: true
       directoryPerDB: true
       syncPeriodSecs: 60
       engine: mmapv1
       mmapv1:
          preallocDataFiles: false
          nsSize: 16
          quota:
             enforced: false
             maxFilesPerDB: 8
          smallFiles: false
          journal:
             debugFlags: 0
             commitIntervalMs: 100
```

What can be going wrong?

PS: /etc/mongod.conf is being used.

```
mongod   10864     1  0 Nov16 ?        03:10:34 /usr/bin/mongod -f /etc/mongod.conf
```

Update- 1 .Tried the same update by changing collection name to a new collection. THat worked! but doesnt explain the issue yet.  2. Changed java driver to 3.0.3, that didnt help.

**Update- 2:(12/9)** Adding Collection Stats, since it is something to do with the collection itself and the java driver. Let me know if something seems awry pls.

```
    {
        "ns" : "2015.events",
        "count" : 827054,
        "size" : 3814018,
        "avgObjSize" : 4722,
        "numExtents" : 22,
        "extents" : [
            {
                "len" : 8192,
                "loc: " : {
                    "file" : 0,
                    "offset" : 20480
                }
            },
            {
                "len" : 32768,
                "loc: " : {
                    "file" : 0,
                    "offset" : 2134016
                }
            },
            {
                "len" : 131072,
                "loc: " : {
                    "file" : 0,
                    "offset" : 2166784
                }
            },
            {
                "len" : 524288,
                "loc: " : {
                    "file" : 0,
                    "offset" : 2297856
                }
            },
            {
                "len" : 2097152,
                "loc: " : {
                    "file" : 0,
                    "offset" : 2822144
                }
            },
            {
                "len" : 8388608,
                "loc: " : {
                    "file" : 0,
                    "offset" : 4919296
                }
            },
            {
                "len" : 11325440,
                "loc: " : {
                    "file" : 0,
                    "offset" : 14356480
                }
            },
            {
                "len" : 15290368,
                "loc: " : {
                    "file" : 0,
                    "offset" : 28827648
                }
            },
            {
                "len" : 20643840,
                "loc: " : {
                    "file" : 0,
                    "offset" : 44118016
                }
            },
            {
                "len" : 27869184,
                "loc: " : {
                    "file" : 1,
                    "offset" : 8192
                }
            },
            {
                "len" : 37625856,
                "loc: " : {
                    "file" : 1,
                    "offset" : 36265984
                }
            },
            {
                "len" : 50798592,
                "loc: " : {
                    "file" : 1,
                    "offset" : 78086144
                }
            },
            {
                "len" : 68579328,
                "loc: " : {
                    "file" : 2,
                    "offset" : 8396800
                }
            },
            {
                "len" : 92585984,
                "loc: " : {
                    "file" : 2,
                    "offset" : 93753344
                }
            },
            {
                "len" : 124993536,
                "loc: " : {
                    "file" : 3,
                    "offset" : 8192
                }
            },
            {
                "len" : 168742912,
                "loc: " : {
                    "file" : 3,
                    "offset" : 125001728
                }
            },
            {
                "len" : 227803136,
                "loc: " : {
                    "file" : 4,
                    "offset" : 8192
                }
            },
            {
                "len" : 307535872,
                "loc: " : {
                    "file" : 4,
                    "offset" : 239136768
                }
            },
            {
                "len" : 415174656,
                "loc: " : {
                    "file" : 4,
                    "offset" : 595939328
                }
            },
            {
                "len" : 560488448,
                "loc: " : {
                    "file" : 5,
                    "offset" : 8192
                }
            },
            {
                "len" : 756662272,
                "loc: " : {
                    "file" : 5,
                    "offset" : 607756288
                }
            },
            {
                "len" : 1021497344,
                "loc: " : {
                    "file" : 6,
                    "offset" : 8192
                }
            }
        ],
        "storageSize" : 3826952,
        "lastExtentSize" : 997556,
        "paddingFactor" : 1,
        "paddingFactorNote" : "paddingFactor is unused and unmaintained in 3.0. It remains hard coded to 1.0 for compatibility only.",
        "userFlags" : 1,
        "capped" : false,
        "nindexes" : 8,
        "indexDetails" : {

        },
        "totalIndexSize" : 348270,
        "indexSizes" : {
            "_id_" : 47123,
            "remoteRequest.uri_1" : 76969,
            "transactionId_1" : 59611,
            "startTime_1" : 39027,
            "endTime_1" : 35235,
            "remoteRequest.queryParams.q_1" : 20328,
            "remoteRequest.queryParams.fq_1" : 38285,
            "elapsedTimeInNanos_1" : 31689
        },
        "ok" : 1
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure that `/etc/mongod.conf` is used? What is the output of `ps ax | grep [m]ongod`? Please add this information by [editing your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/34166991/edit).

Comment: Can you do an insert/update via mongo shell and see whether you are getting the same message?  If so, could you also post the error code from mongo shell. Another thing to check is whether you have free disk space available ? thanks.

Comment: I already did all that. Shell insert works. There is plenty of disk space available too. Am stumped. Going to change drivers and see if it helps.

Comment: @MasterChief can you posted updated `ls` output of your data directory?

Comment: @Pete, do you mean the listing I provided above? those numbers have not changed at all, except the timestamps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `mongod.conf` has a [quota](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/#storage.mmapv1.quota.enforced) enabled for each database. Based on that `mongod.conf` file, you will be unable to create more than 8 database files, which limits you to a max of about 6.4 GB of storage. You mention that you are able to get around this issue by using a new collection, so I am interested in what your data directory looks like now. I would not expect you to be able to bypass this hard limit, however due to internal data structures, it may be possible to "bypass" it for a short time.

You can verify how much actual data is being stored by running the [dbStats command](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.stats/)

```
use 2015
db.stats(1024*1024)
```

This output will tell you how much data you actually have in the db, vs the amount of allocated storage. These numbers will *not* match, this is expected as documents include empty space for padding.

My next question would be, is there are reason you are artificially limiting the amount of storage space your `mongod` can allocate? Perhaps a [capped collection](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/capped-collections/) would better suit your needs? If you could expand on your use, I can perhaps give you a better answer.

Comment: The behavior certainly looks like that and that is the first thing I checked.
I do not need it to be capped. I am obviously missing something.
My Conf file says Quotas is false.
         quota:
             enforced: false
             maxFilesPerDB: 8
          smallFiles: false

So please tell me how I have enabled it.  I need to disable it pronto. :-)

Comment: My suggestion is, drop any settings you aren't using and cycle the `mongod` to ensure they aren't used. To be clear, I have never seen this message when `quota` wasn't enabled.

Comment: Sorry about the delay. We had to simulate this in a test environment first.
Yes, removal of the settings worked. As a precaution we rebuilt the database too from scratch. 
Looks like there is a bug in the code as despite explicit settng of enforced:false, it still is applying the quota limits.