# MongoDB - Quota exceeded error code: 12501

Tags: mongodb

I'm using MongoDB's Sandbox (Version: 3.2.12) database and deployment is on mLab. I have a strange issue while adding/inserting the records (From shell and also from the application).

I have not set any quota limits to the database files.

Error Message:

"error message: quota exceeded error code: 12501”

But i have sufficient memory in database and i can able to add/insert records in other collection apart from “xyz” collection.

However, i have removed some records from "xyz" collection to free up memory and tried again to insert records. E.g. Removed 2 records in collection and after that only 2 records gets inserted.

Can i add more files to my quota, if yes how?

Is there any way to debug this? Or any other solution without dropping database?

Comment: take a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34166991/getting-mongodb-error-on-write-quota-exceeded

Comment: @felix database is deployed on mLab, i think that won't be help.

Comment: @HarshalYelpale Were you able to resolve this?

Comment: Yepp!! by using repairDatabase command...as you mentioned in the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try repairing your database.

> Sometimes it’s necessary to compact your database in order to reclaim disk space (e.g., are you quickly approaching your storage limits?) and/or reduce fragmentation. When you compact your database, you are effectively reducing its file size.
>
> **Compacting Sandbox and single-node plan deployments**
>
> If you are on a Sandbox or single-node plan and would like to try to
> reclaim disk space, you can use MongoDB’s repairDatabase command.
>
> If your fileSize or “Size on Disk” is under 1.5 GB, you can run this
> repair command directly through our UI by visiting the page for your
> database, clicking on the “Tools” tab next, and then selecting
> “repairDatabase” from the drop-down list. Otherwise, you can run the
> db.repairDatabase() command after connecting to your database with the
> mongo shell.

https://docs.mlab.com/ops/#compacting

**The repairDatabase command is a blocking operation. Your database will be unavailable until the repair is complete.**

It may take around 20-30 seconds.

Comment: Mind if i ask you some more.....
I had this issue and your solution seems to have works but I am none the wiser. I will guess, let me know if i am wrong.
We have a overall size limit with the entire database. If this reaches it's limit, it auto increases and/or notify the admins. However, if we do things like delete giant collections, duplicate collections and/or change name, we end up with a lot of hidden memory usage as it doesnt really delete. So this hits a wall and throws this error. It doesnt trigger the "We need more data bell". We need keep this hidden data clear ?
Thanks