# MongoDB out collection (replacing all data, not reduce) Quota exceeded

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Hello I got interesting problem, at least for me.

In our system we are executing many mapReduce jobs, this one is replace type, that means it will replace previous collection data with new data (from mapReduce). Even it's not that many documents we are processing (in current state), let's say around 1000.

But mapReduce algo refusing to execute command and return error

```
Mongo Server error (MongoCommandException): Command failed with error 12501 (Location12501): 'quota exceeded' on server [OURSERVER]

The full response is:
{ 

    "operationTime" : Timestamp(1568706620, 35), 

    "ok" : 0.0, 

    "errmsg" : "quota exceeded", 

    "code" : NumberInt(12501), 

    "codeName" : "Location12501", 

    "$clusterTime" : {...}

}
```

The output scheme looks similar to this (i don't think we are hitting BSON document limit ~16mb).

```
{ 
    "_id" : {
        "firstId" : ObjectId(), 
        "secondId" : ObjectId(), 
        "companyId" : String
    }, 
    "value" : {
        "value1" : Double, 
        "value2" : Double, 
        "value3" : Double, 
        "valu4" : Double
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help or tips.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting MongoDB error on Write - quota exceeded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34166991/getting-mongodb-error-on-write-quota-exceeded)

Comment: Nope i saw that one, doesn't help/ fit to my problem, it was working normally for half a year let's say... It's stopped suddenly

Comment: Then maybe you have now reached the size limit of your database? Are you using mlab?

Comment: `db.stats(1024*1024)` returns `"fsUsedSize" : 14525.45703125, "fsTotalSize" : 100665.28125 ` so i don't know, yes we are using mlab